# ETable quick filtering on more than one column

Tags: java, swing

When using an [Etable](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-netbeans-swing-outline/org/netbeans/swing/etable/ETable.html), you can set a `quick filter` to quickly show or hide parts of your data. It is simple enough:

```
table.setQuickFilter(int Column,  Object filterobject);
```

However, if you try and use two of them sequentially, it will filter on the first and then filter all of your data on the second (rather than just the hidden subset). Is there any easy way, preferably using ETable, to filter on two objects? As in, filter out everything that is not A **and** not B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any easy way, preferably using ETable, to filter on two objects?

I would rather use classes that are part of the JDK so you are not dependent on 3rd party libraries.

The standard JDK provides support for combining filters. You can use an "and" filter. For example:

```
List<RowFilter<Object,Object>> filters = new ArrayList<RowFilter<Object,Object>>(2);
filters.add(RowFilter.regexFilter(filterText.getText(), 0));
filters.add(RowFilter.regexFilter(filterText.getText(), 1));
rf = RowFilter.andFilter(filters);
sorter.setRowFilter(rf);
```

Check out the Swing tutorial on [Sorting and Filtering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) fore more information and examples.

Comment: This is helpful, but I would still prefer to use the 3rd party library. If I cannot find another way to do this within the library and no one else answers, I'll accept this answer.